# a good way to "backup" systemd settings?

Tags: linux, systemd

I wonder if there is a recommended way, or any good experience to show my current systemctl status in a complete way so I can back them up periodically. I understand I could simply backup the output for systemctl combined with things like list-unit-files or --all etc. But sometimes I also want to backup, or at least keep a note on how many files systemd has loaded, so I can at least identify those ones written by me. For example I have numerous .network, .netdev files under /etc/systemd/network folder, a bunch of service.d/ subfolders under /etc/systemd/system/ folder and a lot more. They all add up to a huge mess. Sometimes I really doubt if there exists any better way to keep such a backup other than using pencil and paper (or a text editor), may be just tarball the entire /etc/systemd folder?

Comment: Have you looked into using snapshots with something like btrfs?

Answer (score 1):

why dont you use a configuration management system? for example i can make a host group in foreman and configuring all the aspects in puppet , and when i need to provision a new host with same configuration , i just need to put that host in that foreman host-group , and run puppet agent on that host after os installation.